# Asymptotics of an integral requested

Tags: reference-request, real-analysis, integration, asymptotics

Given an integer $n\geq2$, consider the following integral

$$I_n:=\int_0^1nx^{n-1}\sqrt{\left\vert \frac{\log(1-x)}{\log n}\right\vert} \, dx.$$

**QUESTION.** Is this true? It appears to be so.
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}I_n=1.$$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change variables to $y=n(1-x)$, which gives
$$
I_n=\int\limits_{0}^{n}\left(
1-\frac{y}{n}\right)^{n-1}
\sqrt{1-\frac{\log y}{\log n}}\ {\rm d}y\ ,
$$
then dominated convergence should allow passing to the limit inside the integral
so that
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} I_n=\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} e^{-y}\ {\rm d}y=1\ .
$$

Comment: Really cute! Thanks.

Comment: Sure. My approach hides steps which are not so cute although systematic: doing the Laplace method. I set $x=1-e^{-u}$ because I felt more comfortable with the integration domain $(0,\infty)$. Then I looked for the maximum of the integrand (ignoring the square root), which is at $u=\log n$. Then I recentered to that maximum and let $u=v+\log n$. To make the integral a bit nicer I let $y=e^{-v}$. In the answer, I gave the direct $x$ to $y$ change of variable.

Answer (score 2):

*Just for the fun of playing with a rather unusual integral.*

Write
$$I_n=\frac n {\sqrt{\log(n)}}\sqrt{\log(2)}\int_0^1\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k\,x^{n-1}\frac{\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^k}{k! \,\log ^k(2) }\,dx$$ and, using the gaussian hypergeometirc function
$$\int_0^1x^{n-1}\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^k\,dx=\frac{\, _2F_1(1,k+n+1;k+2;-1)}{2^k\,(k+1)}+(-1)^k \frac{
   \Gamma (k+1)\,\, \Gamma (n)}{2^{k+n}\,\Gamma (k+n+1)}$$

With $L=\log(2)$, the first coefficients $a_k$ are

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
k & a_k \\
 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 \\
 2 & 2 L-1 \\
 3 & 8 L^2-6 L+3 \\
 4 & 48 L^3-44 L^2+36 L-15 \\
 5 & 384 L^4-400 L^3+420 L^2-300 L+105 \\
 6 & 3840 L^5-4384 L^4+5400 L^3-5100 L^2+3150 L-945 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Asymptotically
$$I_n \sim 1+\frac 1 n$$